# How to set scatter legend item size when marker size is greater than 20

Tags: plotly.js

For example, I set marker.size = 20, but The maximum legend element size is 16. So the size displayed on the legend is inconsistent with the size of the real scatter point. Is there any way to solve it?

This is an example
https://codepen.io/Wzhudou/pen/wvYJaVb